# RestTemplate: underzealous ampersand encoding

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

We have code like this that uses the OData to specify the resource (hardcoded with the company code here for simplicity):

```
String uri = "[my_endpoint]/companyprofiles.read?$filter=company/any(company:company/id eq 'C&06')";
HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(null, headers);
ResponseEntity<CompanyProfile> respEntity =
getApiRestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CompanyProfile.class);
```

This fails, because of an ampersand in the Company ID. It works fine with Company IDs that do not have ampersands; e.g., using 'ABCD' returns the resource as expected. Using Postman, the resource is returned if I call

> [my_endpoint]/companyprofiles.read?$filter=company/any(company:company/id eq 'C%2606')

So exchange does some encoding (like spaces to %20), but does not encode ampersands, since they are usually reserved for separating URI variables.

How can I force the ampersand to be encoded? Or can I do the ampersand replacement myself and force the encoding of the percent symbol to be skipped?

EDIT: here's the final answer that worked:

```
String url = "http://[my_endpoint]/companyprofiles.read?$"
  +"filter=company/any(company:company/id eq '{param1}')";
Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("param1", "C&06");
getApiRestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CompanyProfile.class, uriVariables);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try supplying map of parameters to [overloaded exchange method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) to build up URI

Basically that would be something like this :

```
String url = "http://{path}?/$filter={param1} ... ";
Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("path", "[my_endpoint]/companyprofiles.read");
uriVariables.put("param1", "company/any(company:company/id eq 'C&06')");
getApiRestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CompanyProfile.class, uriVariables);
```

Comment: I added after the first line:

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you.

Comment: I added after the first line:
    uri = URLEncoder.encode(uri,"UTF-8");
RestTemplate immediately throws an IllegalArgumentException: "URI is not absolute". The URI being passed to RestTemplate went from "http://my.company.com/..." to "http%3A%2F%2Fmy.company.com%2F...". Am I missing a step or doing this incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not going to paste the actual URI, but basically the original string is "http://my.company.com/api-gateway/events/profileManagement/companyprofiles.read?$filter=company/any(company:company/id eq 'C&06')", and after encoding becomes "http%3A%2F%2Fmy.company.com%2Fapi-gateway%2Fevents%2FprofileManagement%2Fcompanyprofiles.read%3F%24filter%3Dcompany%2Fany%28company%3Acompany%2Fid+eq+%27C%2606%27%29"

Comment: No, stackoverflow edits posts containing URLs. They start with http://.

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow also chops part of the URL. After "profileManagement" where the "..." is should read "companyprofiles.read?$filter=company/any(company:company/id eq 'C&06')"

Comment: try just to change in original uri string `&` to `%26` without encoding.

Comment: The percent symbol gets encoded by RestTemplate. In my original question I included as one possible solution that maybe I could force RestTemplate not to encode the percent symbol, because I had already tried that and failed. Thanks for the suggestion, though. (:

Comment: I had tried that before and it didn't work, but your answer inspired me to try something else, which worked. I'm going to give you credit anyway, because you got involved. (: I'll update my question with the solution that worked.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that. Very much interested in final solution.